# Can't reproduce sequence alignment using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, matrices

I'm new using the TikZ package.

Can someone help-me to reproduce this matrix [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27BRO.png) using Tikz?

[image: Alignment between two sequences]

More precisely the step in figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQxv3.png).

[image: Step]

I tried to do it with matrix but I can't put the number 1 [above left] the node (m-3-3) = +1

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
            nodes in empty cells,nodes={minimum width=7ex,
            minimum height=7ex,outer sep=0pt},
            column sep=1ex,row sep=-2ex]{
                & t & \mathcal{E}   & A & G & C \\
        s   &   &  0            & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 \mathcal{E}    & 0 &  0                &-2 &-4     &-6     \\
              A & 1 & -2                    &+1     &-1     &-3 \\
              A & 2 & -4                    &-1 & 0     &-2     \\
              A & 3 & -6                    &-3 &-2     &-1     \\
              C & 4 & -8                    &-5 &-4     & 1     \\};

         \draw[<-] (m-2-1) -- (m-3-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You need to make the nodes smaller to draw a long arrow automatically. Remove the minimum height and width keys. Make the column/row sep 7 ex and then use `\draw[->,shorten <=3mm] (m-4-4) -- (m-3-3) node[above,pos=.05] {$\scriptstyle 1$};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can place nodes on the paths between matrix elements

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
            nodes in empty cells,nodes={outer sep=0pt},
            column sep=7ex,row sep=7ex]{
                & t & \mathcal{E}   & A & G & C \\
        s   &   &  0            & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 \mathcal{E}    & 0 &  0                &-2 &-4     &-6     \\
              A & 1 & -2                    &+1     &-1     &-3 \\
              A & 2 & -4                    &-1 & 0     &-2     \\
              A & 3 & -6                    &-3 &-2     &-1     \\
              C & 4 & -8                    &-5 &-4     & 1     \\};
\draw ([yshift= 1cm]$(m-1-2)!0.5!(m-1-3)$) -- ([yshift=-1cm]$(m-7-2)!0.5!(m-7-3)$)
      ([xshift=-1cm]$(m-2-1)!0.5!(m-3-1)$) -- ([xshift= 1cm]$(m-2-6)!0.5!(m-3-6)$);

\draw[->,shorten <=3mm] (m-4-4) -- (m-3-3) node[above,pos=.05] {$\scriptstyle 1$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since the superscripts seem to be attached to the node and not to the edges I would suggest a different solution from @percusse's.

First since the superscript seems to be part of the cell's content one solution would be to put the superscript in the cell with something like `{}^{1}-1`. This however gives very little flaxibility in the placement of the superscript.

Instead we could add the superscripts after constructing the matrix but by using the cell's `inner sep` we can add the padding necessary to host the superscript, and then use anchors to position the superscript relative to the north west corner of the cell (borrowing some of percusse's code):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
            nodes in empty cells,nodes={outer sep=0pt, inner ysep=2ex},
            column sep=7ex,row sep=7ex]{
                & t & \mathcal{E}   & A & G & C \\
        s   &   &  0            & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 \mathcal{E}    & 0 &  0                &-2 &-4     &-6     \\
              A & 1 & -2                    &+1     &-1     &-3 \\
              A & 2 & -4                    &-1 & 0     &-2     \\
              A & 3 & -6                    &-3 &{}^{-1}-2     &-1     \\
              C & 4 & -8                    &-5 &-4     & 1     \\};

         % \draw[<-] (m-2-1) -- (m-3-1);
\draw ([yshift= 1cm]$(m-1-2)!0.5!(m-1-3)$) -- ([yshift=-1cm]$(m-7-2)!0.5!(m-7-3)$)
      ([xshift=-1cm]$(m-2-1)!0.5!(m-3-1)$) -- ([xshift= 1cm]$(m-2-6)!0.5!(m-3-6)$);
         \node[outer sep=2pt,inner sep=0pt, anchor=north west] (m-4-4l) at (m-4-4.north west) {$\scriptstyle 1$};

         \draw[->,shorten >=3pt,shorten <=3pt] (m-4-4) -- (m-3-3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With this setup, the `outer sep` of the superscript controls how far from the inner border of the cell the superscript is placed. The `inner sep` of the cell controls how close to the cell's content the superscript is.

[image: Positioning]

The end result is

[image: result]